# Ubuntu 12.04: Google Cloud Print Credentials Error

Tags: 12.04, networking, windows-7, printing

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 and for a while before I have been using Google Cloud Print to print things from my Netbook running Windows 7 Starter to ubuntu printer.
Lately I have noticed that an error occurred that for some reason asks me to enter my email and password however when I click on the baloon message from chrome nothing loads.

I don't get this error on Windows so what happened?? I have tried signing in and out but that did not work. How can I get it to work again?

OR is there another way of sharing a printer from Ubuntu to Windows 7 Starter edition (no IPP on that one)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[[EDIT]] It appears this is a bug in Chromium:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/py5rXlYDM8w

and appears to be resolved in the code: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=154155#c7

However, as of this writing I'm still experiencing the bug, so the release hasn't yet made it downstream through Ubuntu :'(

Soon. Soon...